# CCavenue error decrypting application request

Tags: android, ccavenue

I am integrating ccavenue gateway in my android app. While loading webview I am getting below error

> Transaction Status
>   Error encountered
>   ERROR: Problem in decrypting application request.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is related to access code.

My access code get null while making the request.

Comment: hiii @Neha could u help me in implementing CCAvenue in swift if u have sample pls tell me

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned issue always relates to the incorrect access code/order id or both.The Reason is, while you send the access code and order id to get the secret RSA key from CCAvenue server should always be maintained same throughout the payment process or until the payment transaction request.Because CCAvenue uses this two as a kind of a verification before attempts any transaction request made to it.If it differs, it is unable to detect (or decrypt the application request) which transaction it is going to handle.So it throws an error.Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's due to `TRANS_URL` in the test environment that leads to this error. just changing `TRANS_URL` to production environment

`"https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/initTrans"` works.

I hope, it helps someone.